# Trying to select a sibling value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In code like this:

```
        for(var i=0; i<arSelectedFields.length; i++) {
            $("td[class='ms-formlabel']").each(function() {
                var txtCol = $.trim($(this).text()); // field name
                var fvalue = "";    //field value
                if(txtCol == arSelectedFields[i]) {

                    $("td[class='ms-formlabel'] + td[class='ms-formbody']").each(function() {; // ignoring any field formatting; use html(), if needed
                            fvalue = $(this).text();
                            if(fvalue != "") PrintingHTML += "\n<tr><td class='formlabel'>" + txtCol + "</td><td class='xdata'>" + fvalue + "</td></tr>";
                            else PrintingHTML += "\n<tr><td class='formlabel'>" + txtCol + "</td><td class='xdata'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
                            fvalue = "";

                    });  //each()
                    return false;
                } //else return false; 
            });
        }
```

I have the statement:

```
$("td[class='ms-formlabel'] + td[class='ms-formbody']").each(....
```

What I really want is something like

```
$(this)...td[class='ms-formbody']").each(...
```

but couldn't get it to work. In other words, I want only the `td[class='ms-formbody']` that exists in the row that is currently selected (based upon the value of `td[class='ms-formlabel']`). The closest I could get is the way I show, which starts the collection of formbody elements from the top instead of just the one that applies to the currently selected formlabel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really want to select siblings? You wrote "[...]that exists in the row that is currently selected [...]". Sounds more like you're searching for descendants.

Comment: If you could post the html too.

Comment: You do realize you have a loop within a loop within a loop, and that the first `each()` function will run the same number of times as there are array values in `selectedFields`, and the second `each()` function will run `selectedFields.length` * the first `each()`, with a very similar selector. Seems a bit strange ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is this:

```
$(this).siblings("td[class='ms-formbody']").each(..
```

Comment: Evidently, you understood me correctly because that works like a dream. I didn't know there was such a thing as .siblings.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this + " td[class='ms-formbody']").each(...
```

or

```
$(this).find("td[class='ms-formbody']").each(...
```

Is there a reason that you use the attribute equals selector for class? You should just write: `td.ms-formbody`

Comment: Thank you. I have not tried your response, as Nelson's worked perfectly for me. And your comment about composing the class selector makes perfect sense. I must have copied that scheme from somewhere and have used it ever since.